# ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server: Client unable to establish connection, macOS, django, pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, django, odbc, pyodbc

Everything was working until I restarted my laptop.

I have this setup:

- python 3.8.8
- django 3.1.1
- pyodbc 4.0.30
- `pyodbc.drivers()` shows this: `['ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']`
- SQLServer
- `cat /etc/odbcinst.ini` returns this:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
UsageCount=10
```

- `cat /etc/odbc.ini` returns this:

```
# [DSN name]
 [MSSQL]
 Driver = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
 Server = tcp:<my server>,1433
```

- `odbcinst -j` returns this:

```
unixODBC 2.3.9
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/sgalich/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

- in the django settings:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT'),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```

I reinstalled the ODBC Driver with this [official Microsoft instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15). But it didn't help. I'm still failing to start the django server and facing this error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 320, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(connstr,
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 216, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 226, in _cursor
    conn = super()._cursor()
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Users/sgalich/Desktop/projects/gdp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 320, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(connstr,
django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

That's pretty weird that everything was working for a long time until I restarted my laptop (no OS update, just restarting). May be this issue related to exporting some variables with path? Or may be after the ODBC Driver installation on macOS I need to set up this driver somehow?

P.S.: jdbc driver works without any issues with the same servername, port, user, and password.

**UPD 1:**

Every time when I'm trying to connect I can see these logs from the ODBC driver:

```
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
<...>
            Str In = [DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=<my_server>,1433;UID=<my_username>;PWD=<my_password>;DATAB...][length = 160 (SQL_NTS)]
<...>
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
<...>
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
<...>
        Exit:[SQL_ERROR]
<...>
        DIAG [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection

        DIAG [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute
```

So there is a success message with my real password in it, and then follow the error message, with `Invalid connection string attribute` and `**********` instead of my real password in it. Can some module remove my password with `*`? Maybe this is what prevent me from the connection?

**UPD 2:**

Well, with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69481786/13810466) it started to work, but python started to quit unexpectedly. I reinstalled brew, openssl, all the odbc libraries. And anyway `isql -k -v` returns this:

```
[S1T00][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
[08001][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9
[08001][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLDriverConnect
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with pyodbc, which just started today.  Getting the same error on MacOS.  Strangely, identical code running in Ubuntu in EC2 has no problems, though the driver is different.

Comment: @KT12, yeah, have no issues with jdbc driver.
I've just updated odbc driver logs, do you have similar logs?

Comment: Just checked my logs - I don't have the `Invalid connection string` that you are experiencing.

Comment: I checked the connection string  using https://www.easysoft.com/blog/isql-connection-string.html was more verbose - `[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [OpenSSL library could not be loaded, make sure OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1 is installed]`

Comment: Ultimately, the problem is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69463870/odbc-cant-find-correct-openssl-version-after-upgrading-openssl
I also see the dependency for openssl@3